# How can I get Blogger to display an Adsense ad at the end of each post without also displaying them on the home page?

Tags: blogger, adsense

How can I get Blogger to display an Adsense ad at the end of each post without also displaying them on the home page?

If I put the code right after data:post.body, it shows the ad at the end of individual pages. But it also shows ads on homepage after each post summary. As you probably know, this is a big no-no since Google limits us to three Adsense ads per page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy and simple to show Adsense in specific areas or specific pages of a website. If you want to display Google Adsense ads only in blogger posts so try this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
```

your Adsense code here...

```
</b:if>
```

and try to add Adsense generated code below: `<div class='post-footer'>` line